# Highchart/ROR - Extract data from database table

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, highcharts

I have a rails application that I has highcharts implemented. I am now trying to extend it so that it list the amount of hours spent on a particular project. I have set up a JSfiddle example of what I am trying to achieve. [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yPLjR/307/) What I am intially trying to do is the following:

- Current logged in user goes to their timesheet, selects a project or multiple projects, enters their hours
- The entered amount of hours and selected project(s) are recorded into a ProjectsHours table.
- The Current user can then visit the project hours page which will extract the data from the ProjectsHours table and display it like the JSfiddle example I supplied.

I have done some research on how I think it maybe be done. I saw on the [highcharts website](http://www.highcharts.com/documentation/how-to-use) 
that you can request the data by setting up an Ajax request.

I am writing this question because I am still a beginner in ror and javascript.

I have also implemented a autocomplete function which uses an ajax request and uses JSON to retrieve the data. I set my autocomplete function up as the following, this is slightly irreleveant however I posted the following javascript code for my autocomplete because. I personally think that what I am trying to do will be slightly similar to what I am trying to do. I may be wrong. If someone can correct me thank you.

**Autocomplete**

Application.js

```
function log(message) {
        $( "<div/>" ).text( message ).prependTo("#log");
    }

    $("#tags1").autocomplete({
        minLength: 2,
        source: function(request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/positionlist",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    style: "full",
                    maxRows: 12,
                    term: request.term
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    var results = [];
                    $.each(data, function(i, item) {
                        var itemToAdd = {
                            value: item,
                            label: item
                        };
                        results.push(itemToAdd);
                    });
                    return response(results);

                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: Check the firebug output, what URL does it access and what is the response of the request?

Comment: I have my autocomplete function working fine. What I am trying to do is use highcharts to make an Ajax request using JSON to collect information about the current users timesheet information which consist of the following attributes in the ProjectHours table: :week_commencing, :hours, :user_id, :project_task_id

Comment: I added the sample code above, just to explain that my idea is that I think it may use a Ajax request that was similar to the way I did the autocomplete function. JSfiddle shows what I am trying to achieve, but I don't know exactly how to go about this. I looked at the example on the highcharts website but that was doing something completely different and was using highcharts

Answer (score 1):

When using AJAX with highcharts, I usually do something like:

```
 setInterval(function(){
  $.getJSON('traffic_sources.json', null, function(data) {
      pie_chart("traffic_sources_graph", data.traffic_sources);
  });
 }, 3000);

function pie_chart(div, data)
{
   new Highcharts.Chart({
      chart: {
         renderTo: div,
         backgroundColor: '#dddddd'
      },
      title: false,
      tooltip: {
         formatter: function() {
            return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: '+ this.y +' %';
         }
      },
      plotOptions: {
         pie: {
            allowPointSelect: true,
            cursor: 'pointer',
            dataLabels: {
               enabled: false
            },
            showInLegend: true
         }
      },
      legend: {
         layout: 'vertical',
         align: 'right',
         floating: false,
         labelFormatter: function() {
            return this.name + "(" + this.y + ")";
         }
      },
       series: [{
         type: 'pie',
         name: 'Browser share',
         data: data
      }]
   });
}
```

The JSON for the above looks like this, however this is for a pie chart, for a bar cahrt the data may be slighlty different:

```
{"traffic_sources":[["Direct",5465465],["Search Engines",345876],["Referring Sites",4578767]]}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response, will take a look